How could I formally express: System F cannot express universal quantification over things that are not types?
I'm trying to understand exactly why it is that https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/computational+trilogy states that quantification requires dependent types, and why this wouldn't be possible to achieve with System F. From what I've managed to gather, System F can express quantification, but only over types, and not over elements or predicates.
I'm looking for a way to formalize this statement in order to start working on a proof. How could I express: System F lacks the expressive power to state quantification over terms? Or, lacks the expressive power to state quantification in the way made possible by dependent types?

Your characterization is going to necessarily have to be a bit soft, or presuppose a little about what "stating quantification" means: e.g. since inhabitation in System F is undecidable, you could always code arithmetic $\Pi^0_1$ sentences in a very awkward way.

Cross-posted here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54642/how-could-i-formally-express-system-f-cannot-express-universal-quantification-o and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4968748/how-could-i-formally-express-system-f-cannot-express-universal-quantification-o Please don't do this. And Andrej said on CSTheory.SE, please pick one to keep. I recommend that one, since I think you'll get more luck there.
